# Using Custom Environments in ASP.NET Core

Tags: visual-studio-2017, environment-variables

My appsettings files does work I see them being used according to which launching profile I use however my localhost profile doesn't work because it doesn't seems to exist in the actual Framework I use. Is there anyway to add a custom one such as "localhost"?

[image: My appsettings files does work I see them being used according to which launching profile I use however,,,]

[image: My Localhost profile doesn't work because it doesn't seems to exist in the actual Framework I use. Is there anyway to add a custom one such as "localhost"?]

Edit :

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Program.cs, add a call to `config.AddJsonFile()`:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
            {
                config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Localhost.json", optional: true);
            })
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```